# Cron expression

Tags: unix, cron

I wrote below cron expression to run script monday to friday 16 P.M and 17:30 P.M.Is it correct?

```
0 00,30 16,17 ? * MON-FRI
```

Regards,

Chai

Comment: This is completely off-topic for StackOverflow. I suggest you try another site in the network, perhaps serverfault?

Comment: The easiest way to test it is to change server's date/time and see is Cron fires your task.

Answer (score 2):

you'll have to split this up into to lines:

```
0 16 * * 1-5
30 17 * * 1-5
```

also there's only five columns: minutes, hours, day-of-month, month, weekday